# Text flickers when using css transition opacity and transform rotate in moz

Tags: css

I'm having an issue in moz (work in webkit) text flickers on hover.
Please see this demo for an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/1zy253vv/3/

I tried to add translate3d(0, 0, 0) and backface-visibility: hidden, but nothing worked.

```css
div {
  background: cadetblue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  font-size: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

div:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Saturn</p>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I can see a brief change in thickness when hovered - seems to me like this is to do with the way -Moz- handles font rendering.

Comment: With "flickers" you mean the ~1px jump at the end of the opacity transition?

Comment: Yes. My browser version is the latest version FF 45.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `will-change: opacity;`on the `<p>`

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/1zy253vv/8/

```
p{
opacity: 0;
display: inline-block;
transition: opacity 0.3s;
font-size: 50px;
transform: rotate(-90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
will-change: opacity;
}
```

`will-change: transform;` works too

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, it seems to be the `display:inline-block` on your `p` tag that's causing issues. I can't say for sure why, maybe someone else knows. However, swapping out the CSS for this;

```
p{
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  font-size: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Seems to fix the problem. Fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/1zy253vv/4/

### Update - Firefox Version 44.0.2

[image]

**Also Note** - For webkit, you'll need to reintroduce the 3dtransform and the text-fix.

Comment: For me it is still flickering at the end of the opacity transition (Browser: FF 44.0.2).

Comment: Same browser version (Version  44.0.2) but it seems to work okay for me now in that fiddle. Weird?

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work. Did you try in mozilla?

Comment: @Lewis Maybe we look at different things. Doesn't the text jump one or two pixels after the opacity transition?

Comment: Yep, see the cap in my answer.

Comment: Oh okay, that's really weird

Comment: No it is not display:inline-block on my p tag that's causing issues. Today the latest version is FF 45.0.1

Comment: I dont know what it is then. You can see in the screencap that removing it fixes it for me, at least. Its an odd one